# Multiple Jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict

I'm new to the whole forum thing, so I'll try my best to describe my problem clearly.

I'm trying to use two different jquery scripts on my page, one being [Bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) and the other being [Captify](http://thirdroute.com/projects/captify/). In general, Whenever I try to implement more than one script, they can never work simultaneously. I don't think its a matter of one affecting the other, they just fail to work together AT ALL.

My website is couchkumaras.com, I'm only trying out the captify on my local copy, so you'll see I haven't got it on there at the moment.

Any answers you guys have will be greatly appreciated, I've had this problem for a while, and I've usually been able to compromise, but if it's a small mistake I'm making, it'd be really useful!

Cheers, Finn.

Answer (score 3):

If you open the error console in your browser (Google for a howto), or use a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (Firefox Addon) or the [Chrome web inspector](http://www.braingia.org/webnotes/index.php/google_chrome_web_inspector) you'll see that there is an error when your script executes:

```
JQuery is not defined
    [Break On This Error] JQuery.crash=function(x)...    < line 549
```

You've mistyped `jQuery` as `JQuery` (there shouldn't be a capital J -- it's *lowercase*).

Using the error console can be a great aid in finding out what parts of the scripts that you're using are not functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see captify.js being included anywhere in source.  if you have access could you stick it in there so I can see what's going awry?